# PHP: upload image max 150x150

Tags: php, image, size, limit

How do i make a limit for the size of the image not SIZE but i mean how big it is.. so max 150x150?

```
$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
  if ($image) 
  {
   $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $extension = getExtension($filename);
   $extension = strtolower($extension);
 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
   {
    echo '<h1>Fel bildformat, duuh!!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
   }
   else
   {
 $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
 echo '<h1>Bilden är över tillåten storlek..tyvärr</h1>';
 $errors=1;
}
$image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
$newname="cars/".$image_name;
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
if (!$copied) 
{
 echo '<h1>Kopiering gick fel.. testa igen!</h1>';
 $errors=1;
}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a image editing library for this functionality. Like [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Answer (score 2):

you have to use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/getimagesize) to check image dimensions